# Change global environment variable using a script that is started using xbindkeys?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, xbindkeys

**TLDR:**

- I have a simple shell script that flips an environment variable from value `foo` to `bar`, or the other way round, depending on its current value.
- I use <kbd>F12</kbd> to trigger this script, and I know that works.
- When the script is triggered, the new value doesn't persist when the script ends.

What am I doing wrong?

**Details:**

*1. The script:*

My script checks whether the environment variable is present, or creates it if missing:
`if [ -z $COLEMAK ];then export COLEMAK="qwerty";fi`

Then the script flips the value from whatever it was to the other value:
`if [ "$COLEMAK" == "qwerty" ]
then export COLEMAK="colemak" ; xmodmap ~/colemak.map
else export COLEMAK="qwerty"  ; xmodmap ~/qwerty.map
fi`

Note that besides flipping the variable value, the script uses `xmodmap` to remap the keyboard from one layout to another. This is the core purpose of the script, and that's why I want to trigger it from a function key.

I know that this script only works when it is sourced (`. ~/foo.sh`), and that works well from the virtual terminal. So far so good.

*2. xbindkeys:*

I've configured `.xbindkeysrc.scm` to include `(xbindkey '(F12) "term &")` and that correctly executes the command when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>. So far so good.

I modified that line to read `(xbindkey '(F12) ". ~/foo.sh &")`. I know the script runs because it writes a log line when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, **but the change in the environment variable does not persist after the script ends.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. A program is only able to set environment variables for itself and its child processes.

In your case you could either store the current state in a file (like `~/.active-modemap`) and act on the content of that file. Or you might be able to get the currently used modemap by looking (with grep etc) at the output of `xmodmap -pke` (or any other output of `modemap`).

Comment: Thank you - it makes sense of course that that's the expected behavior but I couldn't come up with an alternative. I'll use one of your suggestions instead!